# SharePoint Nested IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, nested

I have been working on a calculated Nested If Statement in SharePoint that does not work, if anyone if familiar with SharePoint syntax than please help me, here is the statement, I keep getting errors.

=IF(OR([Is 100% of the Sellers work being performed in an office area, performing administration services (i.e. data entry, developing drawing, monitoring phone calls etc.)?]) = "Yes","Low Risk","High Risk",[Is the Contractor/Seller 100% of the time escorted by a XX Employee or XX Representative for consulting or observation only services (i.e. looking but not touching)?] = "Yes","Low Risk","High Risk")

Answer (score 0):

I assume the long sentence is only the field name, so the formula will be converted to the one below

```
=IF(OR([A]) = "Yes","Low Risk","High Risk",[B] = "Yes","Low Risk","High Risk")
```

The issue seems to be the or part as the syntax of OR function is

> OR(logical1,logical2,...),Returns Yes if any argument is TRUE; returns
> No if all arguments are FALSE.

I assume you want to make the field work like Either A or B field value is "Yes", the outcome is `Low Risk`, or it will be `High Risk`.

So the formula shall be like `=IF(OR([A]= "Yes",[B] = "Yes"),"Low Risk","High Risk")`

Replace the actual name with A, B, the formula finally will be

```
=IF(OR([Is 100% of the Sellers work being performed in an office area, performing administration services (i.e. data entry, developing drawing, monitoring phone calls etc.)?]= "Yes",[Is the Contractor/Seller 100% of the time escorted by a XX Employee or XX Representative for consulting or observation only services (i.e. looking but not touching)?] = "Yes"),"Low Risk","High Risk")
```

Comment: The following formula worked as a solution to this issue, =IF(OR([A]= "Yes",[B] = "Yes"),"Low Risk","High Risk"), thanks for you help!

Comment: @DataGeek, Glad to hear it works for you. Please accept it as answer so other community members will know it is a solution when they have similar issues.